# How to alter url query with select box with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change the URL of a link depending on the choice of the select box that the user chooses. The link is set to "admin.php?page=viewdevelopment&developerid='.$developer_id.'&plotnumber=" in the PHP and I then want javascript to add the plotnumber to the end depending on what they choose in the select box.

My current code is this:

```
$('#plot_number').on('change', function(){
    var plot = $(this).val(); // Get the plot number
    var _href = $('.tochange').attr("href");
    //find the closest .tochange
    var select = $(this).parents('tr').find('.tochange');
    select.attr("href", _href + plot);
});
```

Which works however if the user changes their selection twice it repeats it into the url.

Any idea how to stop it repeating?

Thanks

Comment: it is cause you are appending with the href of already changed href not the orginal one.

Comment: Is your change event fired as many times as the user changes drop down selection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you could do , define a global variable in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//define a global variable that stores the original href attribute

orginalHref= $('.tochange').attr("href");

});
```

And Use the same code as above with slight modification :

```
$('#plot_number').on('change', function(){
    var plot = $(this).val(); // Get the plot number
    //find the closest .tochange
    var select = $(this).parents('tr').find('.tochange');
    select.attr("href", orginalHref + plot);
});
```

Or you could store the `href` attribute in an `hidden` new element and get the `href` from there.

And, If you are using HTML5 doctype then there is another workaround. You can add [data attrbutes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

```
<a href class="toChange" href-"someURL" data-href="someURL">Some Link</a>
```

And access it as

```
var _href = $('.tochange').attr("data-href");
```

or

```
var _href = $('.tochange').data("href");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems so simple now.

Comment: Glad it helped you out.